# Unable to insert data into database (PHP MVC)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to allow people to submit their contacts by entering it into a field and it would eventually send it to the database but been trying it for quite some time and cant find out whats wrong with it, if possible do let me know how to return a echo saying "SENT" when its in database. Redirecting to the same page, if possible , dont even need a refresh to get that SENT shown to people.

This is my Controller

```
  $this->config->db_config_fetch();
$this->load->model('skills_model');

//Get Form Data    
$this->input->post('submitsms')  ;
//GEt phone number from field
$type = $this->input->post('phonenumber');
//Call model
$this->skills_model->addsms($type);
}
```

This is my View @ home page

```
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url(''); ?>" name="form"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label>SMS Subscription</label>
  <input type="text" name="phonenumber" placeholder="Phone Number here">      
  <button class="btn btn-info" name="submitsms"  type="submit">Subscribe</button>
  </form>
```

This is my Model

```
function addsms($type){
     $this->db->set('number', $type); 
     $this->db->insert('subscribers');
 }
```

I also tried the following

```
function addsms($type){     
    $sql = "INSERT INTO 'subscribers' ('number') VALUES ($type)";
    $this->db->query($sql);
    echo $this->db->affected_rows();
 }
```

You advice would be of a great help! thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A small example ...........

View file

```
<form action="<?php echo ROOT_FOLDER ?>/add_price" method="post">

<input type="text" class="text" name="amount" value="<?php echo set_value('amount'); ?>" />

<input type="submit" class="submit" value="Approve" /> 
</form>
```

Controller...........

```
public function post_add_price()
{
  $data = array(
'amount'=>$this->input->post('amount'),
 );
$this->model->add_amount($data);  //sending amount to model to insert in dataabse
echo "Amount added to database";
}
```

Model................

```
public function add_amount($data)
{
    $this->insert_helper('order_amount_table',$data);
}

public function insert_helper($table_name, $data_array){
    $this->db->insert($table_name,$data_array);
    return $this->db->insert_id();

}
```

I hope this example will help you .........if you have any doubts ask

Comment: This is working example using in my web application in the one developing right now.............

Comment: Hey Venkat, what if i would like to redirect to myself? action="<?php echo ROOT_FOLDER ?>/add_price" seems like redirecting somewhere else, does it mattter if i remove add_price?

Comment: hey sorry that is not add_price it is post_add_price......that is must and should because when user submitted amount we are calling controller function.......if you wanna redirect just load a view file after inserting price in DB and pass amount array to view file .........

Comment: See the flow will go like this you will show a form to submit amount and when user submitted you will call controller function. In that you will get post data and you will pass that array data to model. In model function you will call a function which will take table name and data array as inputs. After insertion call will come back to controller stating that successful if it is. Then as per your requirement you will call view file which ever you want.......

Comment: what does this do value="<?php echo set_value('phonenumber'); ?>" , because when ever i enter value="<?php echo set_value('phonenumber'); ?>" code or something into my input type="text" everything disappears. the box button etc doesnt show

Comment: hey it's working example i just shared it if you wait for 20 minutes i will try your thing i will let u know

Comment: Yeap i believe its working but value="<?php echo set_value('phonenumber'); ?>" is giving me issue, even before i post i tried set_Value and everything went missing >.< Okay Thank you!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18304/discussion-between-venkat-and-rainbowhat)